# Meteor js, React custom image redirect / meteor WebApp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, web-applications

Hellow guys,

I try to make a customized redirect of images in meteor, so that I just can use shorter custom links which redirect me to the images uploaded in amazon:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use(function(request, response, next) {
      if (~request._parsedUrl.path.indexOf('/image') > -1) {
        response.writeHead(301, {
          Location:
            'https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/my-prepo/folder/imageName123456.jpg',
        });
        response.end();
      }
      next();
    });
```

I can use it very well in external pages like jsfiddle just when I write:

```
<img src="http://localhost:4003/image" />
```

But when I use it in my react frontend like `<img src="/image" />` Then the image doesnt appear, and there is an error in the server:

```
E20180825-11:59:12.452(3) (webapp_server.js:799) Error running template: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
at ServerResponse.setWriteHeadHeaders (/home/bux/.meteor/packages/webapp/.1.5.0.1phld1g.dmro++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:82:19)
at ServerResponse.writeHead (/home/bux/.meteor/packages/webapp/.1.5.0.1phld1g.dmro++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:41:36)
at getBoilerplateAsync.then (packages/webapp/webapp_server.js:791:13)
at /home/bux/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.10.2.12fknlz.thdv++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:43:40
```

What can I do to just use my own link to display the image like `<img src="/image"` ?

Thank you very much in advice
Best regards 
Bukso

Comment: Where these images located? In which file are you calling img tag and where the file is located? show us project folder structure

Comment: The images are located in amazon S3, this is one example:

https://languagepocket-repo.s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/chatrooms/xceGo964qL849ku3z/images/1535189129.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIVKNJGWTCSRFIYKQ%2F20180825%2Feu-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180825T092529Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-Signature=5b489d1957779c7136c5a058c18e08acb84e531fd0ba02cb983f2a7f1d0067dc&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem like that:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use(function(req, res, next) {
  const reqUrlParts = req.url.split('/');
  let urlToRedirect = 0;
  if (reqUrlParts[1] && reqUrlParts[1] === 'files') {
    urlToRedirect = fileHandler.handleUrl(req);
  }
  if (urlToRedirect) {
    res.writeHead(301, {
      Location: urlToRedirect,
    });
    res.end();
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

thank you for your advices. About the expiration link - I handle it by my sistem, that measn I update it automatically if it is expired, and redirect to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, I see you get your images from S3 while you should probably get them through the Cloudfront. The main difference is the caching. Additionally, when you save the images to S3 make sure to have 'expire' and 'cache-control' set so your users cache the images on local devices (if you want that). With Cloudfront you can have a link like assets.yourdomain.com/....your asset.

The easy and safe practice would be to declare a global variable like

```
var IMAGE = 'https//........your cloudfront root '
```

and in the code you end up with something like:

```
<img src={`${IMAGE}/${imagename}.jpg`}
```

If you need full security and entirely "offuscate" the image links/sources, you may use the very highly supported Ostrio Files Meteor package.

P

[image]